# Track each api request and response

Tags: javascript, android, web-services, api, open-source

I have a android app which is working on Post API and Post API are placed on server.
So basically I want to record or track every request from that APP for API and the response of API.

Can any one help if there is any open source script in php or else which helps me in my requirement.

In addition: actually I am seeing this from the server and monitoring prospective like how many request received server for API from client and whats the response of the those requests. Something like a script of something else that track clients calls and response.

For example:

```
sample-api.php   //Post API which are placed on server 
tracking.php  // tracking is a script or any project which tracks the sample-api.php how many time its call and what the response on that time.

mobile1-app  // is the mobile app which call API sample-api.php from server
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want to track it on your app: create an interface class which does the POST, and track it in that class? What does PHP have to do with it? Please post an exact problem statement  + appropiate flags.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, actually i am seeing this from the server and monitoring prospective like how many request revived server for API from client and whats the response of the those requests. something like a script of something else that track clients calls

Comment: please see my edit post what i need to accomplish may be we can do this other way however i need in result call time and response of API. still any query than please let me know... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to track? Response timing? the payload itself?
Not sure if useful, but tools like Moesif Api and Fiddler can track the Request and Response payloads in production or development envs.

Comment: response timing, response of API and how many time any API called

Comment: Moesif would work for that. New Relic could be a 2nd option, they have some good performance monitoring features but focus less on the API stuff.

Comment: Please clearly mention your relationship with Moesif in your answer; otherwise, it could be considered spam. Please see **[the help center here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)** for details. Thank you.